# What does "implementation-agnostic" mean?

Tags: terminology

I'm just wondering what "implementation-agnostic" means? I didn't find any explanation. I mean it in this context: "an implementation-agnostic engineering approach".

Answer (score 10):

The **opposite** of *"implementation-agnostic"* is *"implementation-specific".*
Some examples should make the difference clear:

### Implementation-agnostic

*Synonym: Implementation-**independent***

**Examples:**

- Sorting algorithm ["Quicksort"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
- [Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) written in [Pseudo-Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)

The examples above **can be implemented** with every [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) 
([Assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler), [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC), [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)), [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), ...)

---

### Implementation-specific

*Synonym: Implementation-**dependent***

**Examples:**

- [Device drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver),
- [Machine language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) for AMD (tm) or Intel (tm) [Processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_(computing))

The examples above **run only on** the hardware they are written for.

But also software that depends on or is using other software, [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)), [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), [services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_(systems_architecture)) or [frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) is implementation-specific (for example, although .NETs intermediate language [MSIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) can run on different hardware or operating systems, it still depends on the [.NET framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) and hence is implementation-specific).

Answer (score 3):

This is often used to discuss a problem without committing to a particular implementation. Doing so may lead to choosing an implementation / tool that's best suited for the problem rather than having to worry about the limitations of an already chosen solution during the problem definition.

Answer (score 2):

Agnostic, in this context, means "doesn't care about". So implementation agnostic is something that does not care about the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

To say that a solution is implementation-agnostic is to say that it's not reliant on specific technologies, programming languages etc. Pseudocode would be a good example of an implementation-agnostic tool, as would UML for modelling.