# What, exactly, is memcmp supposed to return?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standard-library, memcmp

I would like to know what the function `memcmp` must return.

I've been searching on the Internet, and usually, `memcmp` definitions state something like the following:

> The memcmp() function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the object pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the object pointed to by s2.

It is never explicitly said what, **exactly**, is returned: is it the difference between two byte values, or is it -1, 0 or 1? I am confused:

- When testing the function `memcmp` in a little program, it returns -1, 0 or 1, even when the difference between the two bytes evaluated is higher than 1 or lower than -1.
- When looking at functions named `memcmp` on the Internet, they almost all return the difference between 2 bytes, as an int, instead of returning either -1, 0 or 1.

Since I can't get a precise enough definition of the function `memcmp`, I ask this question here: what, exactly, is the function `memcmp` supposed to return? Is there an "official" source code somewhere? (I have seen a lot of source codes for `memcmp` but none gave me an answer: I then suppose that they are not the function that is written in the library string.h, at least not on my computer...)

Comment: If it is not specified - it is implementation defined. The guaranteed behavior is in your quote.

Comment: Your quote says it all. Anything beyond that is implementation-specific.

Comment: what does that mean? EDIT: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969057/what-means-implementation-agnostic

Comment: Yes, it is never stated exactly, because there is literally no exact answer, beyond the general assurances that you quoted. No, there is no "official" source code to read, because there is no official C standard library, just implementations with varying degrees of popularity. And because this behaviour is implementation-defined, their source code would not dictate what 'must' happen anyway; all they are required to do is what the Standard says, and nothing more. You'll need to internalise the different kinds of behaviour documented by the Standard to get much further with reading any C docs!

Comment: Its a [three-way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison), the value it returns depends on the params given.

Comment: @Xorifelse It might be. Or might be not.

Comment: thank's for all these answers/comments. Now that I understand the concept of implementation-specific/agnostic, it seems clear to me that it was what I needed to know. I think that the best answer to my question would explain that notion. (If I knew it, I wouldn't have needed to ask this question about memcmp)

Comment: The only *guaranteed* behavior is `< 0`, `> 0`, or `== 0`; testing against specific values like `-1` or `1` is only going to end in heartburn.

Comment: To be honest if I needed to compare memory blocks I had to provide my own one. To check equality usually as well because 1. memcmp is much too expensive to just check if buffers are equal or not 2. It is not time constant. In my opinion this is one of the most useless functions in the standard library (for checking if == it is too expensive & not safe for some applications, for <> is not flexible enough)

Comment: Ty for your opinion, i too would not use it in any case, and even other simple functions i would always prefer to write my own functions. I am trying to reproduce every function of the library string.h, as a training. It already learned me a lot, about constants and void pointers for example.

Comment: @PeterJ: How do you write (portable C) code that out-performs `memcmp()`?  To compare for equality, you have to check that all bytes are the same (though you may be able to speed things up by comparing bigger units than bytes if both the arrays of bytes are well enough aligned and big enough).  If you need a speed-constant solution, it will have to scan all of both chunks of memory, rather than stopping on the first difference which it can do otherwise.

Comment: It's not even implementation defined (which would require implementations to document it, and would imply to most people stability between versions) but *unspecified*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The particular values returned by `memcmp()` are not specified by the Standard. The C11 Draft Standard does say, in [§7.24.4 1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4p1):

> The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions
>   memcmp, strcmp, and strncmp is determined by the sign of the
>   difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both
>   interpreted as unsigned char) that differ in the objects being
>   compared.

So only the sign of nonzero return values from the comparison functions should be taken as meaningful. The latitude given here allows each implementation to interpret these requirements as it sees fit.

Also, note that there is no "official source code"; the Standard is the document that C implementations must adhere to. Even reading the source code for the implementation that you are using to find the underlying method used to generate the `memcmp()` return values, use of these values in code is at best not portable, and is vulnerable to future changes in that implementation.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for not specifying the exact results are

First the exact result doesnt matter. The caller just needs to know one of three results `<`, `=`, or `>`. The defined behavior works. Now the spec could have said return -1, 0, or 1. So why does it matter that this is not said. See second point

Second. By not specifying the exact result the implementer can write code that is very efficient. memcmp could be implemented by counting bits or doing some clever and. or. xor etc that does not naturally produce 1 or -1. So the spec is silent on the exact return value.

Answer (score 2):

As @EugeneSh said, it is not defined.  The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcmp.html) says, in addition to the portion you quoted:

> The sign of a non-zero return value shall be determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of bytes (both interpreted as type unsigned char) that differ in the objects being compared.

Therefore, only zero/nonzero and positive/negative are meaningful tests to apply to the return value from `memcmp`.  Don't rely on the actual values, since they may differ between different C libraries (or maybe even processor architectures).

#### Source example

I found a mirror of the GNU C library (glibc) that someone has put on GitHub.  The [source for `memcmp`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/memcmp.c#L310) takes the difference between the two bytes (line 332), so the return value will generally not be only -1 or +1.  However, a particular library may implement `memcmp` however makes the most sense for the target platform.

Comment: I'm not sure why POSIX was mentioned, but it just paraphrases what the Standard says anyway.

Comment: When looking at the code for the GNU C Library it is important to know that each source file in a top-level directory (like `string/memcmp.c`) is only the _default_ version of some function; they can all be superseded by architecture- or OS-specific code in the `sysdeps` directory.  The string functions in particular are often replaced with hand-optimized assembly versions for specific CPUs (e.g. [`sysdeps/x86_64/memcmp.S`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/memcmp.S)).

Comment: @zwol-- that is a very interesting point, and I was not aware of it. I had just added comments to my answer to the effect that reading the actual source and using the findings may be vulnerable to future changes in the library; but you suggest that this may not even be valid today, yes?

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes, I mean to suggest that, for instance, `memcmp("a", "z", 1)` might return a different negative value depending on which memcmp implementation is actually used.  It can even vary at runtime - take the same binary and run it on a machine that has a different set of vector instructions, the library will pick a different inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

It does not specify what integer will return, it specifies that the result can be compared with `0`.

Any values returned by an implementation is correct if it accomplish this test.